# workaround for final == and != (equals and not equals) methods in scala DSL

Tags: scala, equals, dsl

So I'm wrapping bits of the Mechanical Turk API, and you need to specify qualification requirements such as:

```
Worker_Locale == "US"
Worker_PercentAssignmentsApproved > 95
...
```

In my code, I'd like to allow the syntax above and have these translated into something like:

```
QualificationRequirement("00000000000000000071", "LocaleValue.Country", "EqualTo", "US")
QualificationRequirement("000000000000000000L0", "IntegerValue", "GreaterThan", 95)
```

I can achieve most of what I want by declaring an object like:

```
object Worker_PercentAssignmentsApproved {
  def >(x: Int) = {
    QualificationRequirement("000000000000000000L0", "IntegerValue", "GreaterThan", x)
  }
}
```

But I can't do the same thing for the "==" (equals) or "!=" (not equals) methods since they're declared final in AnyRef. Is there a standard workaround for this? Perhaps I should just use "===" and "!==" instead?

(I guess one good answer might be a summary of how a few different scala DSLs have chosen to work around this issue and then I can just do whatever the majority of those do.)

**Edit:** Note that I'm not trying to actually perform an equality comparison. Instead, I'm trying to observe the comparison operator the user indicated in scala code, save an object based description of that comparison, and give that description to the server. Specifically, the following scala code:

```
Worker_Locale == "US"
```

will result in the following parameters being added to my request:

```
&QualificationRequirement.1.QualificationTypeId=000000000000000000L0
&QualificationRequirement.1.Comparator=EqualTo
&QualificationRequirement.1.LocaleValue.Country=US
```

So I can't override `equals` since it returns a `Boolean`, and I need to return a structure that represents all these parameters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a little survey of what various DSLs use for this kind of thing.

[Liftweb](http://www.scala-liftweb.com/liftweb_api/net/liftweb/http/js/JsExp.html) uses `===` in Javascript expressions:

```
JsIf(ValById("username") === value.toLowerCase, ...)
```

[Squeryl](http://squeryl.org/sessions-and-tx.html) uses `===` for SQL expressions:

```
authors.where(a=> a.lastName === "Pouchkine")
```

[querydsl](http://blog.mysema.com/2010/09/querying-with-scala.html) uses `$eq` for SQL expressions:

```
person.firstName $eq "Ben"
```

[Prolog-in-Scala](https://github.com/sonoisa/Prolog-in-Scala/blob/master/PrologInScalaSample.scala) uses `===` for Prolog expressions:

```
'Z === 'A
```

[Scalatest](http://www.scalatest.org/scaladoc/doc-1.2/org/scalatest/Assertions%24Equalizer.html) uses `===` to get an `Option` instead of a `Boolean`:

```
assert("hello" === "world")
```

So I think the consensus is mostly to use `===`.

Answer (score 4):

If you look at the definition of `==` and `!=` in the scala reference, (§ 12.1), you’ll find that they are defined in terms of `eq` and `equals`.

`eq` is the reference equality and is also `final` (it is only used to check for `null` in that case) but you should be able to override `equals`.

Note that you’ll probably also need to write the `hashCode` method to ensure
∀ o1, o2 with `o1.equals(o2)` ⇒ `(o1.hashCode.equals(o2.hashCode))`.

However, if you need some other return type for your DSL than `Boolean` or more flexibility in general, you should maybe use `===`, as has been done in [Squeryl](http://squeryl.org/sessions-and-tx.html) for example.

Comment: I edited the question to make it clearer that `equals` really isn't a viable option here since it returns `Boolean`. Thanks for the link to Squeryl though!

Answer (score 0):

I've been considering a similar problem.  I was thinking of creating a DSL for writing domain-specific formulas.  The trouble is that users might want to do string manipulation too and you end up with expression like

```
"some string" + <someDslConstruct>
```

No matter what you do its going to lex this as a something like

```
stringToLiteralString("some string" + <someDslConstruct>)
```

I think the only potential way out of this pit would be to try using [macros](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/macros/overview.html).  In your example perhaps you could have a macro that wraps a scala expression and converts the raw AST into a query?  Doing this for arbitrary expressions wouldn't be feasible but if your domain is sufficiently well constrained it might be a workable alternative solution.